# Ping on LAN fails even without firewall

Tags: windows, networking, ssh, ping

Since the last windows update I have severe problems with my network card. Pings on LAN (including Virtual Machines) are causing general failures. Also SSH connections to my VMs fail. A ping in the internet does not fail. I have tried this with and without my firewall disabled.

Unsuccessful ping to the default-gateway of my LAN:
[image: Unsuccessful ping to the default-gateway of my LAN]

Successful ping to 8.8.8.8:
[image: Successful ping to 8.8.8.8]

SSH to the Virtual Machine (Debian 8) denied:
[image: SSH to the Virtual Machine (Debian 8) denied]

Thank you for any information.

Comment: This requires more information about the IP address and subnet mask of all your machines. You obscured the IP address used in your ping screenshot then proceeded to show us a different IP address in your SSH screenshot. So at this point your post is completely indecipherable. There is zero reason to obscure these IP addresses, assuming they are all private IPs.

Comment: The IP addresses (at home it is 10.0.0.0/24) should not matter as this error occurres on every LAN, not only at home. Also connectivity cannot be the problem as all my traffic out to the internet goes to my gateway. The problem has to be with the host. However, I cannot find a reason for the ping to fail. Also in wireshark i can‘t seem to find any outgoing arp/ping requests.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it. I uninstalled my VPN client (NordVPN), to test if that was a problem. This solved it. For some reason the VPN network adapter blocked all local connection. Maybe I used some incorrect settings.

Edit:

[The reason for the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrwjs.jpg) was that I used the option "Invisible on LAN" on NordVPN. I assumed that it just encrypts my connection on LAN (lower layers). However, it seems to completely block connections on LAN.

[Without Invisible on LAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEpPP.jpg) it works fine.